# How to override order behavior for the Angular library ng-fullcalendar?

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

I'm using Angular and I want to override order behavior (alphabetically for example). How can I do that?

There is a solution for AngularJS by overriding a Javascript file, but in my case I use Angular.

Comment: the order of what, exactly? What problem specifically are you facing? Your question is far too vague for anyone to be able to help you. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then update your question. Thanks.

Comment: the order is order of events

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventOrder shows you the options provided by default in fullCalendar. You can specify a function to sort the events any way you  like (of course as mentioned, it only applies to events which have the exact same start time and duration...otherwise they are sorted by those properties instead, as is logical in a calendar). I don't think the fact you're using Angular makes any real difference, you still need to set the option in fullCalendar.

Comment: My wish is to apply a custom events order even if the start time are different
I said "Angular" because I do not know how to redefine the order overloading the  fullcalendar library

Comment: Since it's not a defined feature of fullCalendar, you can only do that by modifying the fullCalendar source code. I don't know how you're loading that file but that's what you need to change.

Comment: But think about it logically...you want to list the events in a different order to the order they start in? How are you going to do that on a **calendar** which is entirely based on the idea of showing things **at the time they occur**. I think users will be confused if they see Event 1 appearing before Event 2 even if Event 2 starts earlier in the day. It will look like a bug.

Comment: At least I want to apply custom sorting on events with the same start date

Comment: well I still don't think it's particularly logical (and clearly neither did the fullCalendar maintainers, otherwise they'd have made it a feature), but if you _really_ want to do it, then you have to alter the fullCalendar source code as I mentioned.

Comment: Thanx ADyson , for more clarification
my expected result is
https://i.imgur.com/iYZv5Rw.png
and my current result is
https://i.imgur.com/Wm60zTi.png

Comment: ok. Good luck then. As I've mentioned twice already, you need to get the source code and edit it. It's likely too big a job for anyone to tackle just to put an answer on here.

Comment: I imagined having the possibility to override a .ts file as a solution to this problem , but I keep custom sorting events with same begin date and duration. thanx

Comment: well fullcalendar is written in TypeScript and then compiled, so yes that's a possibility if you really need to do so. Of course if you then want to upgrade fullCalendar in future you have to port your changes to the new version as well. IMHO your time might be better spent making a [feature request](https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features) to see if official support can be added for your requirement. Of course there's nothing to stop you from coding it as a feature yourself and submitting a patch, either.

Comment: great , I created a feature request for this (https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/4378)

Comment: Great. However, I think what you've written is probably stretching the definition of a _detailed_ description, which is what the instructions at https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features tell you to write. I'm only saying that because I wouldn't want you to find that your request is ignored due to inadequate information. (To be clear, it's not my decision - I have nothing to do with the fullCalendar project, but certainly as a developer if I received a feature request I would expect it to have a lot more information in it than that).